# Throwing dice 10 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

> A fair dice was thrown 10 times, and it's been registered that all numbers 1-6 have appeared at least once. If this is true, what's the probability that at least 2 sixes have appeared?

At first I thought I should calculate the amount of combinations of die throws that the 6 numbers that have definitely appeared as $\binom{10}{6}$, then dividing it by the amount of all possible outcomes, $6^{10}$, and then multiply it with the probability of throwing at least 1 six in the remaining 4 throws, since one has already been registered, $P(A)= 1-\left(\frac56\right)^4$.

Then I began to have serious doubts, as $6^{10}$ is an insanely large number, and whether I'd even need the possible outcomes of the 6 numbers that were thrown, and the only solution I could think of is that the all that matters would be the 4 throws we don't know about, regardless of in which throw we got one of the numbers 1-6, and that the answer would be the already mentioned: $$P(A)= 1-\left(\frac56\right)^4$$

Now I'm having minor doubts about this approach, and don't have a solution to this problem, so I would really appreciate if someone could tell me if this way of thinking is right or wrong.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting problem. I believe your 'major and minor doubts' are well founded, and for pretty well-expressed reasons. The simulation in my 'Answer' show that the formula $1 - (5/6)^4$ is not correct, and maybe my accompanying remarks will point in the direction of a correct analytic solution.

Comment: I have added a 'combinatorics' tag, hoping it gets the attention of someone who can give a correct combinatorial argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Computing the Probabilities**

Using [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to compute the number of ways to get all five faces ($1$-$5$) with $d-n$ dice, we get that the number of ways to have $n$ sixes with $d$ dice is
$$
\binom{d}{n}\left[\binom{5}{0}5^{d-n}-\binom{5}{1}4^{d-n}+\binom{5}{2}3^{d-n}-\binom{5}{3}2^{d-n}+\binom{5}{4}1^{d-n}-\binom{5}{5}0^{d-n}\right]
$$
Therefore, the probability of getting $2$ or more sixes, given that we have at least $1$ six is
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^d\binom{d}{n}\left[\binom{5}{0}5^{d-n}-\binom{5}{1}4^{d-n}+\binom{5}{2}3^{d-n}-\binom{5}{3}2^{d-n}+\binom{5}{4}1^{d-n}-\binom{5}{5}0^{d-n}\right]}{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^d\binom{d}{n}\left[\binom{5}{0}5^{d-n}-\binom{5}{1}4^{d-n}+\binom{5}{2}3^{d-n}-\binom{5}{3}2^{d-n}+\binom{5}{4}1^{d-n}-\binom{5}{5}0^{d-n}\right]
}
$$
The results for different values of $d$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
d&p&\text{approx}\\\hline
6&0&0.000000\\
7&\frac16&0.166667\\
8&\frac{17}{57}&0.298246\\
9&\frac{17}{42}&0.404762\\
\color{#C00000}{10}&\color{#C00000}{\frac{1606}{3261}}&\color{#C00000}{0.492487}\\
11&\frac{293}{518}&0.565637\\
12&\frac{18868}{30083}&0.627198
\end{array}
$$

---

**Applying the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion**

Above, it is mentioned that we used inclusion-exclusion to compute the number of ways to get all five faces with $d-n$ dice.

To do this, we let $A_k$, for $k\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, be the arrangements without face $k$. Thus, the number of ways to arrange $d$ dice with some face missing, is
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\bigcup_k A_k\right|
&=\overbrace{\ \sum_k\left|A_k\right|\ }^{\binom{5}{1}4^d}-\overbrace{\sum_{k_1\lt k_2}\left|A_{k_1}\cap A_{k_2}\right|}^{\binom{5}{2}3^d}+\color{#9000B0}{\overbrace{\sum_{k_1\lt k_2\lt k_3}\left|A_{k_1}\cap A_{k_2}\cap A_{k_3}\right|}^{\binom{5}{3}2^d}}\\
&-\underbrace{\sum_{k_1\lt k_2\lt k_3\lt k_4}\left|A_{k_1}\cap A_{k_2}\cap A_{k_3}\cap A_{k_4}\right|}_{\binom{5}{4}1^d}+\underbrace{\sum_{k_1\lt k_2\lt k_3\lt k_4\lt k_5}\left|A_{k_1}\cap A_{k_2}\cap A_{k_3}\cap A_{k_4}\cap A_{k_5}\right|}_{\binom{5}{5}0^d}
\end{align}
$$
Let's explain how to compute the purple term, the total of the intersections of three of the $A_k$. The others will be similar.

$\binom{5}{3}$ is the number of ways to choose the $3$ faces to be excluded. Once those have been excluded, there are $2$ faces onto which to map the $d$ dice; that is, $2^d$ ways. Thus, the purple sum is
$$
\binom{5}{3}2^d
$$
Thus, to count the number of ways to get all five faces with $d$ dice, we subtract from the number of ways to arrange all $d$ dice:
$$
\binom{5}{0}5^d-\binom{5}{1}4^d+\binom{5}{2}3^d-\binom{5}{3}2^d+\binom{5}{4}1^d-\binom{5}{5}0^d
$$
which is used above.

Comment: Thanks much. I removed entry for 7 rolls of the die from my simulation results (within the margin of simulation error, but possibly misleading), now that you have provided analytical results.

Comment: I just wish to thank you and @BruceTrumbo for very insightful answers. I was sure there was something wrong with my approach, but wasn't sure what it was.

Comment: Overall, I hope you have already learned to trust your intuition. When you think you smell a rat, you should look for rats. Sometimes simulation can improve your sniffer. (Sometimes in applications simulated results are good enough.) But for a serious theoretician there is seldom a substitute for an analytic result. In particular, I hope you will look for several examples where the inclusion-exclusion principle solves messy problems and learn it well--starting with this one. The recent addendum here is very nice! (Then maybe item-matching.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid it's back to the drawing board.
Here is a simple simulation in R
based on a million performances of the experiment. Values approximated
by this simulation should be accurate to around 3 places--good enough to see that the result is not consistent with $1 - (5/6)^4$

```
m = 10^6;  n = 10;  u = s = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  dice = sample(1:6, n, rep=T)
  u[i] = length(unique(dice))
  s[i] = sum(dice == 6) }
a = mean(u==6);  b = mean(s >= 2);  bs = mean((u==6)&(s>=2))
a; b; bs; bs/a
##  0.27155     # Aprx prob all six faces seen
##  0.515156    # Aprx prob at lest two 6's seen
##  0.133668    # Aprx prob both of above
##  0.4922408   # Aprx P(at least two 6's | all six faces seen)
mean((s >= 2)[u==6])
## 0.4922408    # Another way to get cond'l prob
1 - (5/6)^(n-6) # Incorrect formula
## 0.5177469    # Incorrect answer
```

I tried this with various $n$'s,  with the following
results for 8 through 11:

```
 n    Correct    Incorrect
 8    .299       .366
 9    .407       .427
10    .492       .518
11    .565       .598
```

The discrepancy between the simulated result and the proposed incorrect solution grows with $n$. I believe this is because
the number of 6's grows with $n$, and there are corresponding increasing ambiguities.

Essentially the proposed solution, for $n = 10$ is to take it as
given that we already have seen faces 1 through 6 (when ranked), and now as
a separate independent experiment we only need to get at least
one additional 6 in four additional rolls. In fact, we have already
done 10 rolls, and if there is already more than one 6, it is
unclear which to ignore.

> It may help to consider a simpler experiment. Toss a fair coin
>   four times. Given that we have at least one head and one tail,
>   what is the probability that we have at least two heads.
>   The correct answer based on a sample space of 16 equally likely
>   outcomes has 14 outcomes with at least one head and one tail.
>   Of these there are 10 with at least two heads. So the correct
>   conditional probability is $10/14 = 5/7.$
>
> However, a bogus argument corresponding to the incorrect answer
>   to the main Problem would say, we already have at one head and one tail, now we just need to make sure at least one of the other two tosses
>   is a head, for an obviously incorrect probability of $3/4$.

I'm not an expert in combinatorics (especially at this time of day), so I won't try to give an
argument for a correct analytic solution to the main problem.
But I have reasonable confidence in my simulation and my reasons
for believing we do not yet have a correct analytic solution.

Answer (score 0):

cause all the numbers appeared at least once you have 1 certain 6 among your 6 throws and you should calculate the probability of appearing at least one 6 in 4 throws, so you should calculate the probability of no 6 appearing which is equal to $\left ( \frac{5}{6} \right )^{4}$ and then subtract it from 1. So I think your answer is correct.

Comment: An incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You know there was at least one roll each of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Therefore, 5 of the rolls can be counted definitely out. You also know that a 6 was already rolled once. Therefore, all you need to calculate is the probability that in 4 more dice rolls, you'll get a 6 at least once again.

Does that simplify the problem enough for you to solve it?

Comment: Not a hint in the right direction.